# Aria engine - changing block size

Tags: mariadb, storage-engine

It's possible to change aria_block_size from default 8192 without recreating tables? I want try 1024 or 2048 but after change in my.cnf and restart mariadb I got this errors on aria tables:

```
#138 - Wrong block size 8192; Expected 1024
```

My db have about 120Gb and many tables, so export/delete/import will cause many hours of outage and this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

> 1. change engine from aria to myisam
> 2. stop mysql, add aria_block_size = 1024 to my.cnf
> 3. delete aria_log_control file in mysql directory
> 4. start mysql
> 5. convert myisam tables back to aria

This process is safe for data, can be done without outage (only one fast mysql restart) and much faster then re-create tables and import data.